# Image for a background in a <div> using only CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I am new to HTML / CSS and this is just a test page. I have a div that contains an image of a person and I want to add a quote of him next his image, but I can't fix the image to fill the whole div's width and height. Can you please help me! 
P.S. I don't know how to use scripts yet so is it possible to make it only by using CSS or should I leave this for now?

```
<div id="napoleon">
    <img src="images/napoleon.jpg" />
</div>
<div>
    <q>If you can see it and you can believe it, you can do it.</q>
    <p>Napoleon Hill</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If you have text in the div, how is the image supposed to fill the whole div? I'm a bit confused because your title makes it seem like you want a background image but the body of your post says otherwise.

Comment: @Clint I mean I want to resize the image to fill the full width and height of the div, the quote should be in another div, that's my mistake. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the image in css instead of using an image tag.

CSS `background-size: cover` will make the image fill the area. `background-position: center` means it won't align to the top left corner.

```css
.napoleon { background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/200/200'); }
.beethoven { background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/100/200'); }
.tesla { background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/200/100'); }

.quote {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.quote{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote napoleon">
  <h2>Napoleon</h2>
  <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."</p>
</div>

<div class="quote beethoven">
  <h2>Beethoven</h2>
  <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."</p>
</div>

<div class="quote tesla">
  <h2>Tesla</h2>
  <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."</p>
</div>
```

If you wish to make the `img` as big as the div, it's much more complicated:

```css
.quote {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}
.quote img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.quote {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200">
  <h2>Napoleon</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
<div class="quote">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100">
  <h2>Beethoven</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
<div class="quote">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/200">
  <h2>Tesla</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! I did not change the path or anything else, but when I used the both classes the magic was there!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with CSS!

```
#napoleon {
  background-image: url('images/napoleon.jpg');
  background-size: cover; /* this makes the image fill the container */
  background-position: center;
}
```

Just make sure to adjust the URL of your image, and remove the image from the div.

Comment: It's not loading the image at all. I have done it exactly the same as yours :(

Comment: @vahanpwns in the folder of the project (where my index.html is) I have only one subfolder (images) and inside it I have only this image (napoleon.jpg) so the URL is "images/napoleon.jpg", right?

Comment: @TsenkoAleksiev is your CSS file in another folder next to the images folder? Then you'd need to change the URL to "../images/napoleon.jpg"

Comment: @TsenkoAleksiev Johannes is right, the url in the css file is relative to the css file

Comment: A ***super*** **important** thing to note is that relative paths in CSS files are relative _to the CSS file!!_  So if you have `...website/` and `...website/css/` and `...website/images/` then the `url()` in the css must refer to `url('../images/napoleon.jpg')` (relative to the css file) or must use an absolute url `url('/images/napoleon.jpg')`